# Adicionar Primefaces ao projeto

Tags: java, primefaces

Galera qual é o procedimento (passo a passo) pra eu adicionar o primefaces ao meu projeto?
Ja tenho o jar na máquina, mas esse jar ele fica dentro do Maven dependencies?
tenho que realizar qual alteração no web.xml e no pom?

Answer (score 1):

Não é necessário baixar o `jar` no seu PC. É só incluir as seguintes dependências no seu `pom.xml` (o tema é opcional):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>5.3</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
    <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Não precisa alterar nada no seu `web.xml`. Para usar os componentes no *XHTML*, basta declará-lo no cabeçalho:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
```

Comment: Não funcionou, o projeto roda mas sem o primefaces

Comment: Tem algum *log* pra gente ver?

Comment: Então, eu configurei novamente o projeto para receber o maven, com isso ele baixou as dependencias de jar, inclusive a do prime faces, ai rodei e funcionou...valeu Victor

Comment: Beleza, não se esqueça de marcar a resposta como correta. Abs

Comment: como que eu faço? só clicar na seta pra cima? rsrsr seu nao sou novo nesse trein aqui kkk